# Como relacionar a mesma tabela sem entrar em conflito?

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela de usuários, e uma tabela de curtidas.
A tabela de curtidas possui: `usuario_curtido` e `usuario_curtiu`.

Quando executo

```
select u.usuario_nome from usuarios u
JOIN te_curtidas_usuarios c
ON c.curtida_usuario_curtido = u.usuario_id
ORDER BY c.curtida_data LIMIT 15
```

os usuários entram em conflito — recebo sempre o mesmo usuário.

Resposta:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["usuario_nome"]=>
    string(11) "Maria Joana"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["usuario_nome"]=>
    string(16) "Daniel Bonifacio"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["usuario_nome"]=>
    string(16) "Daniel Bonifacio"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["usuario_nome"]=>
    string(16) "Daniel Bonifacio"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    ["usuario_nome"]=>
    string(16) "Daniel Bonifacio"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    ["usuario_nome"]=>
    string(16) "Daniel Bonifacio"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(1) {
    ["usuario_nome"]=>
    string(15) "Daniel Oliveira"
  }
}
```

Tabela:
[image: Tabela de curtidas]

Comment: use o GROUP BY u.usuario_nome. ou melhor GROUP BY u.usuario_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

Pelo que percebi você não está relacionando a mesma tabela, está relacionando a tabela `usuarios` com `te_curtidas_usuarios` através de JOIN. Neste caso irão retornar todas as ocorrências da segunda tabela `curtida_usuario_curtido` em que `curtida_usuario_curtido` for igual a `usuario_id`, repetindo os nomes `usuario_nome` que estão na primeira tabela `usuarios`.

Para evitar que o mesmo usuário seja repetido, você deve agrupar o resultado da consulta pelo `id` do usuário usando GROUP BY:

```
select u.usuario_nome from usuarios u
JOIN te_curtidas_usuarios c
ON c.curtida_usuario_curtido = u.usuario_id
GROUP BY u.usuario_id
ORDER BY c.curtida_data LIMIT 15
```

Comment: Esta resposta não lida com o caso de usuários homônimos. GROUP BY deveria agrupar pelo ID do usuário, ou se apenas interessa a listad de nomes, usar DISTINCT em vez de GROUP BY cujo objetivo é produzir agregados (sum, count, etc.) e não remover ocorrências distintas.

Comment: Porque ela "funciona".

Comment: @epx Oi amigo. Fiz uma atualização na resposta. Veja se agora está melhor. Obg e desculpe as brincadeiras.